# Nginx detecting 301 requests

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have tons of 301 redirects to my server from spam domains to reduce my google rank. How can I detect the 301 request and also is it possible to filter it by whitelist domain list? Because also I have self 301 domains list.

Best regards,